# Creating an IR Spectrum using Gaussian ADMP Calculation

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

I have a Gaussian 16 trajectory for a small cluster of water molecules carried out with ADMP technique. I was wondering if anyone knows how to compute the IR spectrum from the information in the trajectory.
Thank you

Comment: Dear Victor, if you have an XYZ File, you can use Travis (by Brehm and Kirchner) to calculate power spectra. For an IR spectrum, you need to compute the dipoles - normally done using Wannier centers, the analysis to make the spectrum is also possible in Travis: http://www.travis-analyzer.de/